# Search the keyword on all pages

Tags: jquery, regex

Below is the code I am using to search the keyword in the datatable. The issue is below code, search the keyword only on the given page. It wont search on the complete datatable. I want to search the whole table for the given keyword. Please help.

Lets say, I searched keyword on first page of the datatable. If I search the same keyword on 3rd page of datatable, it shows 0 results.

```
$(document).ready(function()  



    {$('#searchProf').keyup(function()
        {
            searchTable($(this).val());
        });
    });

    function searchTable(inputVal)
    {

        var table = $('#displayCCAccounts');

        table.find('tr').each(function(index, row)
        {
            var allCells = $(row).find('td');
            if(allCells.length > 0)
            {

                var found = false;
                allCells.each(function(index, td)
                {

                    var regExp = new RegExp(inputVal, 'i');
                    if(regExp.test($(td).text()))
                    {
                        found = true;
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                if(found == true)$(row).show();else $(row).hide();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What is your data source?  Can you search against that, and then reconstruct the table with the results?  Also, have you looked at some of the table libs already in existence?

Comment: I cant search against the database everytime due to performance and bulk data. which table libs you are suggesting?

Comment: Are you loading all the data and paginating on clientside, or do you just load the paged data each time?https://www.datatables.net/ is really popular.  I've had generally good experiences with it.

Comment: Loading data for each page. Not sure if above code could work in that case. I am new to this